# What is csWinFormsBlackApp?

Tags: vb.net

Does anybody know what is csWinFormsBlackApp?

When I try to install software which is published and try to open the soft it gives csWinFormsBlackApp stopped working error.

Comment: Have you contacted the software publisher?  Are you running the correct version of the .NET framework?

Comment: It appears to be the default application/namespace name for C# WinForm applications. If this program was shipped with that namespace you can bet that the program isn't designed very well.

Answer (score 0):

very sorry for late response because of health matters. Didn't meant to be rude.

I think it is some kind of error which i solved by correctin connection strings adress using ./SQLEXPRESS instead of the one vs uses from the beginning..

It's all working now.

Thanks for your help and sorry again for late answer.

I passed a fairly simple surgery and recovered now :) TG..

See you again.
Sertac